# Access Violation C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, pointers

I am new to c++, and I'm facing the Access Violation exception.
The problem is as follows, I have backend.h file which contains the struct

```
struct Config
{
 ....
}conf;
get_conf();
```

The implementation in backend.cpp

```
Config get_conf()
{
return conf;
}
```

backend.cpp and backend.h are compiled and built to generate a dll.
This dll is included in a VS solution that way

```
Config config = get_config();
Config *g_config = &config;
```

The code compiles and run fine but it throws an exception when the function is called

```
First-chance exception at 0x75d6d36f in BA.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x002ec494..
First-chance exception at 0x75d6d36f in BA.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x002ebe28..
First-chance exception at 0x75d6d36f in BA.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..
First-chance exception at 0x77962d37 in BA.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x41ce5ab2.
Unhandled exception at 0x77962d37 in BA.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x41ce5ab2.
The program '[4624] BA.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
```

I think the problem has something to do with pointers & struct please help me out

Answer (score 4):

The question does not make much sense, and it indicates that you should probably start with a good book or tutorial to understand the basics (declaring a variable in a header file is probably not a good idea, the function declaration is wrong in the header), the whole terminology you are using is *strange*...

Anyway, as of your particular problem now, the best advice is to run the application inside a debugger, and you will see what is going on. My first guess (looking at a crystal ball) is that you are creating a `Config` object with automatic storage duration in a scope (`Config config = get_config();` --this *creates* a new object in the current scope that is a copy of the `conf` object) and then obtaining a pointer to it (`Config *g_config = &config;` -- pointer to `config` object in the current scope, not to global `conf`) that you then pass around and later use outside of the scope when the object has already been destroyed.

Another option is that you are facing the *initialization order fiasco*, if those two lines are not inside a context, in which case, you could be trying to copy a yet uninitialized `conf` object into `config`.

The `std::bad_alloc` itself is an exception that is thrown when `new` fails to allocate memory, and it can happen if the system is out of resources (probably not the problem here) or if the request is incorrect.

Comment: I think its the first option .. pardon me I am a java developer and returning objects in java is by reference .. what exactly do you suggest?

Comment: @Poka: it depends greately on what you want to *do* (as in what the semantics of the operations are), why are you obtaining the pointer for? You need to define the problem before you can get to a solution.

Comment: what I simply want is to get the struct then set its attributes by values that I get from the user.

Comment: A common approach (that would be similar to Java also) would be to have the `conf` object be a `static` class member (note that `static` also has other meanings) and then provide an accessor as you would in Java... no need to complicate things...

Comment: can I use it without declaring a class because there is no class currently?

Comment: @Poka: You should really start with a good book. As for your last question, there is no need to add classes to the mix, but you need to understand what the declarators in the language mean and how to use them. For this particular question, you can try and search how this would be done in C, as in this particular case (limiting to no classes) the C solution can be implemented in C++ (and improved by the use of references).

Answer (score 1):

If you have this declarations in the header:

```
struct Config
{
 ....
}conf;
get_conf();
```

then it is likely to be equivalent to:

```
struct Config { ... } ;
Config conf;
int get_conf();
```

"likely", because in C omitting the return type implied that the return type is int. This is not the case in C++, but MSVC's compiler isn't really so standards-compilant so it might have missed that, esp. if you have warning disabled.

If so, this may cause the declaration

```
int get_conf();
```

to be linked with definition:

```
Config get_conf() { ... }
```

in the source file. If this links, such call would crash your program.

Comment: my fault .. its Conf get_conf(); I missed it while typing

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be with the construction of the structure, it might go out of order when you are compiling i.e before the structure is created/initialized , you are assigning some address to the pointer.

So, make sure all the GLOBAL data creation/initialization happens in the same cpp compilation unit

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a compiler to confirm, but this is at least part of the problem.  `conf` defined in the header won't work.  If you used the header in two cpp files you would get duplicate symbols.

I would guess that Kos is correct in the why you get the message you do with the seg fault.  You may have some warnings (don't disable them) that would confirm that.

My other guess would be that it may be trying to use a declared but uninitialized variable.

This is what I would expect, assuming you don't want to make a bunch of copies of your `Config` object.

```
// .h
struct Config
{
  // ...
};
Config &get_conf();

// .cpp
Config &get_conf()
{
  static Config conf;
  return conf;
}

// some other file
Config &conf = get_conf();
conf.value = 5;
```

Comment: I think what you're saying is exactly what I need because I want only one instance of the conf, but I tried it and unfortunately still the same exception, what do you think ?!

Comment: I have a question .. doesn't declaring the conf inside the function cause a problem, because every-time a new conf will be created?

Comment: @Poka Yoke No, when you declare conf as static, it will only be created the when you use it the first time.

Comment: @Poka Yoke put debug messages in the constructors and deconstructor and learn what its doing.  Chances are you are missing some small part and its copying.